# Do int ref parameter get boxed?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

Say I have the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    int a = 5;
    f1(ref a);
}

public void f1(ref int a)
{
    if(a > 7) return;
    a++;
    f1(ref a);
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

**Output is :**

```
8 8 8
```

**i.e.** when the stack unwinds the value of the ref parameter is maintained.

Does it mean that adding `ref keyword` to `int parameter` causes it to get boxed?
 How does the actual stack look like during the recursive call?

Comment: Possibly my lack of knowledge, but lets have a go: passing a value type by ref causes it's position on the stack to get passed rather than the value itself. It has nothing to do with boxing and unboxing, correct?

Comment: From MSDN: "There is no boxing of a value type when it is passed by reference."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Passing a value type by reference causes its *position* on the stack to get passed rather than the value itself. It has nothing to do with *boxing* and *unboxing*. This makes thinking about how the stack looks during the recursive calls rather easy, as every single call refers to the "same" location on the stack.

I think a lot of confusion comes from [MSDN's paragraph on boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Boxing is name given to the process whereby a value type is converted into a reference type. When you box a variable, you are creating a reference variable that points to a new copy on the heap. The reference variable is an object, ...

Possibly confusing you between two different things: **1)** the "converting" as you will, of a *value type* to say an object, which is by definition a *reference type*:

```
int a = 5;
object b = a; // boxed into a reference type
```

and **2)** with the passing of a value type parameter *by reference*:

```
main(){
   int a = 5;
   doWork(ref a);
}
void doWork(ref int a)
{
    a++;
}
```

Which are two different things.

Comment: Probably the best explanation... Note that "on the stack" is specific case mentioned in the question, value type does not have to be allocated on the stack. Maybe saying "absolute position (i.e. on stack)" may be more generic - not sure how it reads for people without C/C++ background.

Answer (score 11):

It's easy to create a program that could give different results depending on whether `ref int` gets boxed:

```
static void Main()
{
    int a = 5;
    f(ref a, ref a);
}

static void f(ref int a, ref int b)
{
    a = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

What do you get? I see `3` printed.

Boxing involves creating copies, so if `ref a` were boxed, the output would have been `5`. Instead, both `a` and `b` are references to the original `a` variable in `Main`. If it helps, you can mostly (not entirely) think of them as pointers.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the existing answers how this is implemented:

The CLR supports so called managed pointers. `ref` passes a managed pointer to the variable on the stack. You can also pass heap locations:

```
var array = new int[1];
F(ref array[0]);
```

You can also pass references to fields.

This does not result in pinning. Managed pointers are understood by the runtime (in particular by the GC). They are relocatable. They are safe and verifiable.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Console.WriteLine(a);`
will be executed after recursion is finished. Recursion is finished when value of int becomes 8. And to make it to 8 it has recursion for 3 times. So, after last it will print 8 and then pass control to recursion above which will print 8 again as variable referred has value became 8.

Also check ILDASM output

```
.method public hidebysig static void  f1(int32& a) cil managed
{
  // Code size       26 (0x1a)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldind.i4
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.7
  IL_0003:  ble.s      IL_0006
  IL_0005:  ret
  IL_0006:  ldarg.0
  **IL_0007:  dup**
  IL_0008:  ldind.i4
  IL_0009:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_000a:  add
  IL_000b:  stind.i4
  IL_000c:  ldarg.0
  IL_000d:  call       void ConsoleApplication1.Program::f1(int32&)
  IL_0012:  ldarg.0
  IL_0013:  ldind.i4
  IL_0014:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_0019:  ret
} // end of method Program::f1
```

Comment: That's all correct, but it does not answer any of Pawan's questions. :)

Comment: As far as I know boxing is not happening. It is just pushing latest value on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a boxing.

There is clear explanation in MSDN [ref keyword documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx):

> Do not confuse the concept of passing by reference with the concept of reference types. The two concepts are not the same. A method parameter can be modified by ref regardless of whether it is a value type or a reference type. There is no boxing of a value type when it is passed by reference.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaken in saying the `int` parameter is being boxed. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx),

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or
>   to any interface type implemented by this value type

What you have here is an `int` parameter being passed by reference, specifically it's a "value type" being passed by reference.

You can refer to Jon Skeet's excellent [explanation](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) on parameter passing for details.

Comment: Yes, but to the runtime the parameter type of `f1` is not `System.Int32` it is the so called ref type `System.Int32&`, which does not report itself as being a value type.